# Is $0$ the null space of the integral operator with kernel $G(r,r') = \frac{\exp(-ik|r-r'|)} {|r-r'|}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, greens-function, electromagnetism

Let $G(r,r') = \frac{\exp(-ik|r-r'|)} {|r-r'|} $, where $r$ and $r'$ are position vectors in a domain $D$ of $\mathbb R^3$ and $k$ is a positive real constant. Suppose that $h$ is a continuous real valued function defined in $D$.

Does $\int_D G(r,r') h(r') dr' = 0$ imply that $h = 0$ in $D$? Is there a well-known theorem that applies to this question and/or a proof that answers it?